# Переменная в имени переменной php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Нужно сделать запрос в базу данных.
Например:

```
$t=2`
UPDATE schedule SET days='$_POST[days$t]'
```

Думаю, по запросу понятно, что я пытаюсь сделать. PHP выдает ошибку при попытке выполнения. Есть какое-то решение или стоит прибегать к формированию строки перед запросом?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но ничего не понятно

Comment: решение может быть: `{$_POST[days$t]}`. А проще пользоваться подготовленными запросами!

Comment: я бы дополнил до `{$_POST["days$t"]}`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский И что вот это `days$t` должно означать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov На деле, из формы передаются данные в виде:
$_POST[time1], $_POST[time2] и так далее. Мне нужно как-то циклом прокрутить все эти переменные, чтобы не плодить код. Я вот и думаю, можно ли это как-то сделать?

Comment: @Danchyg1337 можно типа такого http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/146caba4dd553002cb6e62b97d1e26ba9fae2dd9 .........но на самом деле `$_POST[time1], $_POST[time2]` - это глупость, если можно передать массив

Comment: `foreach($_POST ...)`

Comment: `Мне нужно как-то циклом прокрутить все эти переменные, чтобы не плодить код.` - как несколько переменных и цикл соответствуют коду с одной переменной `UPDATE schedule SET days='$_POST[days$t]'` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский $t - переменная цикла. Просто для краткости объявил ее заранее, что сути не меняет. На самом деле, я решил проблему, перейдя по вашей ссылке, спасибо. Просто объявил в начале цикла все нужные мне переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если запрос начинается с двойной кавычки, можно попробовать так:

`"UPDATE schedule SET days='".$_POST['days'.$t]."' WHERE   ....` продолжение запроса

Comment: никогда не собирайте запрос конкатенацией. Используйте подготовленные запросы

Comment: @rjhdby - спасибо за комментарий. Ваш ответ заставил задуматься. Я даже задал вопрос на эту тему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761190/php-двойная-или-одинарная-кавычка-и-конкатенация-что-быстрее

Comment: мой коммент был не про конкатенацию как таковую, а про создание с помощью него SQL-запроса