# PHP двойная или одинарная кавычка и конкатенация - что быстрее

Tags: php

Для того, чтобы собрать строку можно использовать два варианта.
Первый с помощью двойных кавычек (данные парсятся) например:

```
$text = "Здесь любой текст и переменная $test";
```

Или второй вариант с помощью конкатенации:

```
$text = 'Здесь любой текст и переменная '.$test;
```

Какой вариант будет работать быстрее? И зависит ли разница в скорости от количества переменных в строке? Просто услышал мнение, что конкатенация занимает больше времени. Хочется услышать мнение экспертов.

Comment: вы сколько наносекунд хотите сэкономить на этой операции?

Comment: в php7 в 2017 - одинаково

Comment: `чтобы собрать строку можно использовать два варианта` - больше)

Comment: `услышал мнение, что конкатенация занимает больше времени` - вообще по логике именно переменная в строке - должна занимать больше времени, т.к. парсеру нужно пройти по строкам, собрать по определенному шаблону переменные в строке, вычленить их оттуда, заменить значениями и т.д......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Логично так думать. Но вот  статья `https://habrahabr.ru/post/40072/`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то парсер делает небось, а в рантайме уже подготовлено все.

Comment: Предложите больше вариантов. Я в основном пользуюсь вторым.

Comment: @StackOverflow живя в 2017-ом я склонен не доверять статьям 2008-го (с отрицательным рейтингом кстати)

Comment: @teran ничё знаю) проще сделать тесты, чем гадать, так или иначе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский про тесты согласен.

Comment: Ну а вообще когда работаешь на сегодняшних языках программирования, то ваш вопрос не кому извините `не интересен`. Тем что в больших проектах часто из за не правильной логики вы уже тратите очень много серверного времени. а все эти стандарты настолько мало тратят времени что это и не важно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а тесты будут?)

Comment: @АлександрБелинский кому нужно - пусть делает

Comment: Снова холивары)) Да, разница есть, но проявляется она только при сотнях тысячах запросов, в остальном можете писать как вам привычнее/удобнее/принято в вашей команде.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский затестил

Comment: @АлександрБелинский протестил! :)

Comment: @StackOverflow прогнал ваши 2008е тесты (:

Comment: @teran Ну и как ? Что получилось?

Comment: @StackOverflow опубликовано ответом

Comment: @DaemonHK, так в том-то и дело, что когда просто пишешь код - тут пофигу. А вот тебе РАЗ! и надо такую дикость сделать - прогнать 1трлн. строчек разово. А за последние несколько лет ты кроме php ничего не использовал. Учить для этого теперь другой язык?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

раз уже вчера с @АлексейШиманский затронули тесты, а @StackOverflow поделился ссылкой на древнюю как динозавры статью с какими то тестами от 2008 года, то решил проверить один из этих тестов в 2017м.
Железо почти из той же эпохи i7-980x и 10 ГБайт памяти в наличии
win10х64, Open Server, проверяем на пхп 5.6 и 7.0.22.

запуск тестовых функций несколько переписан.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4;$i++){

    $f = "quotes_$i";
    $ts = microtime(true);

    call_user_func($f, $_1, $_2, $_3, $_4, $_5, $_iterator);

    $time = microtime(true) - $ts;
    print "$f - $time\n";
}
```

тестируются 4 функции, в каждой по 5 млн итераций, в строку подставляется 5 переменных:

1. подстановка в строки вида `"qwe $var asd"`
2. подстановка в строки вида `"qwe {$var} asd"`
3. конкатенация с одинарными кавычками `'qwe'.$var.'asd'`
4. использование `sprintf`

для пхп 5.6х32 результаты следующие (5 запусков, средний):

```
1. 4,143 сек
2. 3,827 сек
3. 6,866 сек
4. 12,378 сек
```

при запуске в консоли результат в аналогичный.

для пхп 5.6х64 время несколько увеличивается (здесь и далее по 3 запуска, средний)

```
1. 4,198 сек
2. 4,182 сек
3. 8,646 сек
4. 12,572 сек
```

При переходе на пхп 7.х ситуация кардинально меняется

```
1. 1,625 сек
2. 1,612 сек
3. 2,862 сек
4. 13,886 сек
```

в отличие от 5.6 для пхп 7.х х64 наблюдается ускорение

```
1. 1,149 сек
2. 1,156 сек
3. 2,871 сек
4. 12,143 сек
```

отсюда выводы:

- вызов функции форматирвоания `sprintf` очевидный аутсайдер, и это понятно, т.к. переключение стека и т.п. тоже требует приличных ресурсов.
- х64 версия для 5.6. работает несколько дольше, чем х32, хотя в случае пхп 7.х ситуация обратная и выигрывает х64 вариант.
- вариант с конкатенацией всегда проигрывает варианту с подстановкой в строку, и если для пхп 5.6 в 1.5-2 раза, то для пхп 7 в 2 раза и более.
- в пхп 7. варианты 1 и 2 подставноки в строку в двойных кавычках идентичны по скорости, хотя в 5.6 первый несколько проигрывал.
- пхп 7 в 2.5-3.5 раза быстрее в данных операциях чем 5.6.

Comment: А можно теже тесты только со множеством подстановок? Или линканите ссылки.

Comment: @ErroR тестовый скрипт был взять отсюда https://dumpz.org/2560/

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно подстановка быстрее, и суда по комментам на php.net 11 лет назад тоже была быстрее. Прямо мир рухнул)

Comment: Хотя при маленьких строках конкатинация незначительно быстрее и только на больших как в тесте подстановка быстрее. И еще сложный синтаксис "{$d}" незначительно быстрее чем простой "$d". @teran если ли инфа какая по данному вопросу или только игры с чёрной коробочкой?

Comment: @ErroR я бы сказал, что `$id` и `{$id}` разница для пхп 7 в рамках погрешности измерений, одна сотая мс на 5млн итераций. я мб мышкой по экрану больше водил, вот и разница :) но более детальной инфы нет, я лишь повторил тесты на которые ссылались в комментах. Число подстановок/конкатенаций в строке и длины строк, конечно, тоже будут влиять. сложный синтаксис может быть быстрее, т.к. там сразу ясно, где заканчивается имя переменной, и не надо всю символьную таблицу перебирать для поиска соответствия.

Comment: что-то натупил,  результаты в секундах, конечно, а не мс

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php) логичнее предположить, что пример с одинарной ковычкой будет работать быстрее, так как php не ожидает ни каких переменных и прочего. Однако на моем компьютер iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012), с установленным MAMPом + php 7.0.22, результаты обоих строк оказались одинаковы, хотя, мой пример не показатален.

```
<?php

$start = Tester::getTimeSum(microtime());
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
$test = 1;
    //echo 'privet ' . $test;
    echo "privet $test";
}

$end = Tester::getTimeSum(microtime());
var_dump(Tester::getDiff($start, $end));

class Tester
{

    /**
     * @param string $time
     * @return float
     */
    public static function getTimeSum(string $time): float
    {
        list($milliseconds, $timestamp) = explode(' ', $time);
        return $milliseconds + $timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $startTime
     * @param float $endTime
     * @return float
     */
    public static function getDiff(float $startTime, float $endTime): float
    {
        return $endTime - $startTime;
    }
}
```